# How to skip @Pattern validation on a blank field?

Tags: java, regex, jsf, bean-validation

I am using JSR303 bean validation annotations in my JSF managed bean to validate text input. Here are the annotations:

```
@Size(min=0, max=20, message = "Value cannot be more than 20 characters")
@Pattern(regexp = "[^|]", message = "Invalid entry. See field description.")  
private String txt;
```

The `@Pattern` annotation throws an error when a pipe character is found in the string. But when a user leaves the field blank and clicks submit, the error is also thrown. Why is this happening when the field is blank?

Comment: You might have an issue with txt being a null when submitted. try ...txt = "" for giggles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the regexp `[^|]` needs exactly one character to match. You should use a quantifier: `[^|]*`

Here are some tests:

```
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[^|]", "")); // false
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[^|]", "a")); // true
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[^|]", "aaa")); // false
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[^|]*", "")); // true
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[^|]*", "aaa")); // true
System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[^|]*", "a|a")); // false
```